# Dell poweredge R310 rackserver

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

cant able to join the Domain in Dell Poweredge R310 server its giving an error as follow

( An Active Directory Domain Contorller for the Domain could not be Contacted )

Comment: What have you done to diagnose it? dsdiag results? Ping? Does it see the network properly, can it see the AD controller? There has to be more detail than this, otherwise there's like a hundred things to check...

Comment: Your title has absolutely nothing to do with the question. Please change it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have connectivity between the DC and member server, ten times out of ten this problem is related to DNS.

Make sure the server that you're joining is using your AD DNS servers.